# Add transparent color code in apex tag

Tags: visualforce, javascript, css

Hi in my meter gauge I have to add a transparent white color

```
<apex:gaugeSeries dataField="size" donut="50" colorSet="#78c953, #FFFFFF" tips="true"   />
```

i.e. I need: `colorSet= "#78c953, tranparent color"`

What color code should i use?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you can achieve what you want is going to depend on what colour formats the charts support. I suspect it's only going to allow hex colour codes which means you can't specify an alpha (transparency) value.

One thing to try would be using the `rgba` style notation: `rgba(255,0,0,0.3)` where the first three values are the values for red, green and blue in the range 0-255 (You'll have to convert your hex values to decimal) and then a final floating point value that ranges from 0-1 and determines transparency, with 0 being transparent and 1 being opaque.

I suspect the API won't support this format, and if the generated charts are just images then you'll be out of luck. If they're generated with elements then you might be able to use some Javascript trickery to change styles, but that would more than likely be overkill.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I think I should try with javascript but don't know how can this be done. 
Can any body help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the reply I did some work around and got this solution.

and to make #FFFFFF transparent

.metergaugeCSS span div div svg path:nth-child(4){
  opacity: 0.4;
}